# Redis HMGET unsupported when using Sentinel

Tags: php, redis, moodle, sentinel

I have a Redis 5.0.6 cluster with one master and one replica and using Sentinel for high availability. Cluster mode is disabled.

I setup the cluster on Kubernetes using the Redis HA Helm chart https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/redis-ha.

I'm using Redis for caching in Moodle, an open source PHP application. I'm using PHP 7.0

The issue I am having is that when I connect to Sentinel from PHP I get `Exception - Unsupported operand types` when calling `HMGET`. When I just connect to Redis directly I don't get that error.

When I log into the master Redis container and call `HMGET` from the Redis command line it works fine.

Why would Sentinel not support `HMGET`? Is there a way to enable support for `HMGET` when using Sentinel?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?